# Probability of first to draw red ball from urn without replacement

Tags: probability, summation, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, polya-urn-model

There are R red and G green balls in a box. Alice and Bob pick one ball from the box in turns without replacement. First one to draw a red ball wins. What is the probability that Alice wins if she draws first?

Here is my attempt - Could someone please advise where I went wrong?

For any draw, the probability of picking a red ball is equal to picking $k$ green balls before that and a red ball on $k+1$ draw.

$\displaystyle P(i=k)=\frac{1}{(k+1)}\frac{\dbinom{G}{k}\dbinom{R}{1}}{\dbinom{N}{k+1}}=\displaystyle \frac{R}{(k+1)} \frac{G!}{k!(G-k)!}\frac{(N-k-1)!(k+1)!}{N!}$

$\displaystyle=\frac{G!}{N!} \frac{(R+G-k-1)!}{(G-k)!}.R\frac{(R-1)!}{(R-1)!}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\binom{R+G}{G}}\dbinom{R+G-k-1}{G-k}$

Let $P(A)$=Alice wins, $P(B)$=Bob wins. Let $P(x)=P(A) - P(B)$. Therefore $P(A) =\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}(1+P(x)) $

$\displaystyle P(x)=\frac{1}{\dbinom{R+G}{G}} \sum_{k=0}^{G} (-1)^{k} \dbinom{R+G-k-1}{G-k}$

If $G$ is even, $-1^k=-1^{G-k}$; using binomial identity

$\dbinom{n}{k} = -1^k \dbinom{k-n-1}{k}$, we get,

$\displaystyle P(x)=\frac{1}{\dbinom{R+G}{G}} \sum_{k=0}^{G} \dbinom{-R}{G-k}$

$\displaystyle P(x)=\frac{1}{2^N\dbinom{R+G}{G}} \sum_{k=0}^N \dbinom{N}{k} \sum_{k=0}^G \dbinom{-R}{G-k}$

$\displaystyle P(x)=\frac{1}{2^N\dbinom{R+G}{G}} \sum_{k=0}^N \sum_{k=0}^G \dbinom{G+R}{k} \dbinom{-R}{G-k}$

Using Chu-Vandermonde identity, we get,

$\displaystyle P(x)=\frac{1}{2^N\dbinom{R+G}{G}} \sum_{k=0}^N \dbinom{G}{G}$

$\displaystyle P(x)=\frac{N+1}{2^{N}\dbinom{R+G}{G}}$ - which seems wrong e.g. set $G=0$

Comment: I haven't checked your work past the computation of $P(i=k)$ (which looks good to me)*, but instead of introducing $x$ why not just obtain $P(A)$ by summing $P(i=k)$ over $k$ even? 
* though note that we could write it immediately by recognizing that it's just the number of ways of arranging $(G-k) + (R-1)$ balls since the first $k+1$ places are already known.

Comment: Everything through your first line that starts P(x)= looks correct, but then the next line with the -R in the combination loses me.  Are combinatorics even defined for negatives like that?

Comment: @user78090: Yes: $\binom{x}k$ is defined for all real $x$ and non-negative integer $k$ by $$\binom{x}k=\frac{x^{\underline{k}}}{k!}\,,$$ where the numerator is a falling factorial $$x(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-k+1)\,.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let random variable $R_1$ be the number of draws to get the first red ball.  For $k\in\{1,\dots,G+1\}$, we have
\begin{align}
P(R_1=k)
&= \left(\prod_{d=0}^{k-2} \frac{G-d}{R+G-d}\right)\frac{R}{R+G-(k-1)} \\
&= \frac{\binom{G}{k-1}}{\binom{R+G}{k-1}}\frac{R}{R+G-(k-1)}\\
&= \frac{\binom{R+G-(k-1)}{G-(k-1)}}{\binom{R+G}{G}}\frac{R}{R+G-(k-1)}\\
&= \frac{\binom{R+G-(k-1)}{R}}{\binom{R+G}{G}}\frac{R}{R+G-(k-1)}\\
&= \frac{\binom{R+G-k}{R-1}}{\binom{R+G}{G}}.
\end{align}
So the probability that Alice wins is
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor G/2 \rfloor} P(R_1=2k+1)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor G/2 \rfloor} \frac{\binom{R+G-(2k+1)}{R-1}}{\binom{R+G}{G}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{R+G}{G}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor G/2 \rfloor}\binom{R-1+G-2k}{R-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{R+G}{G}} \sum_{k=0}^G\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\binom{R-1+G-k}{R-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\binom{R+G}{G}}\left(
\sum_{k=0}^G\binom{R-1+G-k}{R-1}
+\sum_{k=0}^G(-1)^k\binom{R-1+G-k}{R-1}
\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\binom{R+G}{G}}\left(
\binom{R+G}{R}
+(-1)^G \sum_{k=0}^G\binom{-(G-k)-1}{R-1}
\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{(-1)^G}{2\binom{R+G}{R}}
\sum_{k=0}^G\binom{-(G-k)-1}{R-1}
\\
\end{align}

Comment: This alternative solution looks correct but could you please advise where I went wrong in my solution above?

Comment: @pavybez I think your error arises from using the same index $k$ for two different summations and then trying to combine them.

Comment: @pavybez you also need parentheses around $-1$ when it is raised to a power.